# Export html table with form input values in it using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, export-to-excel, form-fields

I have an HTML table. Inside its `<th></td>` tags there are form input fields with types text, number, date and time. I have the following JavaScript through which I can export the table to Excel. When I fill up the fields and click the export button, the table is exported with blank fields:

Any solution please?

```js
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()

// SelectAll Checkboxes
function selectAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('select_all[]');
    for (var i in checkboxes)
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking isn't widely supported by all browsers, and export to Excel with pure Javascript is largely an exercise in futility.  You may get it working in one, but guaranteeing it across browsers and as support changes will be dicey at best.

The better, cleaner, easier approach is to implement a grid plugin that stores your table data and has built-in export logic that will work cross-browser and with reliable results....they've taken the time to work through browser idiosyncrasies and delivery reliable results in .xls or .xlsx formats.  My grid of choice is [Datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/excelTextBold), and it's dead simple.  But there are also several other options out there.